# Are there any intermediary companies in Netherlands that allow you to work with your existing clients?

Tags: outsourcing, local-business

I'm a freelancer working with a US company. I want to move to the Netherlands, so I started looking for a job, but my client suggested another solution: to find an intermediary company in Netherlands that can hire me and outsource me back to my current client.

I earn enough on my current contract to qualify for Highly Skilled Migrant visa, the only problem I need a recognized sponsor in Netherlands to hire me.

I started searching for companies like this, but so far no luck: it seems that most outsourcing firms have only their own existing employees, and at least from looking at their sites, there's no mention of anything like this. So, is this a valid option? Are there companies that do this? And is it legal? Maybe there's some special term for this?

Comment: Many things are done good or right. As a general rule, when it is too easy to be good or you find clients giving you free advice, better look somewhere else.

Comment: @AvramCosmin, I eventually reached the same conclusion. Better to look for traditional employment.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you where hired and rented back to your original client, you would no longer be a freelancer, but a paid employee, so this could belong into workplace.
2. The company hiring you will want some compensation for their Indetermination, also taxes and social security will probably be deducted so don´t expect to get the same kind of money you are currently getting. Try [an income calculator](https://thetax.nl/) to get a feel for it. Expect your employer to want some 30% profit share (+/- depending how complicated the deal my be)
3. Under the circumstances in (2), any Company offering paid development work should be happy to hire you, as it seems you are bringing in a customer who will fully cover the expenses.

Comment: Why the downvote?